# Mouse offset in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I recently started making my new game in LibGDX and I'm encountering a small problem. I found out how to make the player rotate towards the mouse, but it's always offset by a few degrees. The problem is that I don't know the exact amount of degrees it is offset by. Does anyone know how to fix this? I don't have any code that changes the mouse or anything like that.

Comment: Well what code do you have? Which values and coordinates do you use?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7478ad97587e1ac64616 That's currently most of my code, except variable declaration and other misc stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at your code, you seem to have an error in your angle calculation... You seem to have switched the x and y coodinates. The implementation in libgdx looks like this:

```
public float angle () {
    float angle = (float)Math.atan2(y, x) * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
    if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
    return angle;
}
```

For convenience, you could easily use the `angle()` methods in libgdx's Vector2 class.

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html#angle-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/1ac475880a41168b815e53ebeeeb917a08c49a28/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.java

Also, I'd advise you to use the `unproject()` method in your camera. This will transform the screen coordinates (pixels) to the coordinate system used by your Camera. These don't necessarily need to be different, but might be. And therefore it's always better to implement it, in case you change anything later.

Changing these two things should solve your problem.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't seem to work. I checked again and it's (x, y), not (y, x). Using Camera.unproject didn't seem to change anything either. Thank you for your answer, though!